# Showing video stream at higher bitrate

Tags: css, html5-video

I have a webpage where I can add multiple video streams and display them like a mosaic.

This looks like this:
[image: Mosaic]

The videos can be resized, but when they get too small, the bitrate will lower (the stream adapts to the size of the video) and artefacts start to become visible.

I was wondering if there was any way I could keep the videos at a fixed size (large enough to get a higher bitrate) while scaling them down for the mosaic.

I've tried using the CSS `scale` feature, but I couldn't achieve the desired outcome. Maybe it's not possible at all, but I'd appreciate any tips you might have (keep in mind that I'm unable the change the stream itself).

Thanks!

Comment: are you serving these as multi-bitrate fragmented MP4 files? one way you could do is play the streams via a hidden element at the larger size and copy (with scaling) to a canvas but then you may end up trying to exceed available bandwidth and having a different cause of suboptimal behavior

Comment: They're actually just `.m3u8` http(s) links that I'm adding as a source to the `video` tag, so I'm not really sure how they're set up (might also differ from one stream to the other). The bandwidth remark is a valid one though. Would you happen to have more information on how to implement the technique you're referring to?

Comment: @ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ Does your M3U8 contain links to other M3U8 files of different resolutions? so to answer _"Showing video stream at higher bitrate"_ would mean accessing the preferred higher bitrate as the actual M3U8 link given to the video tag.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Wouldn't the "resolution change" issue just transfer to the drawn pixels of Canvas items when a user resizes the page? I suspect Asker is using a third party system to play the M3U8 files (like VideoJS or HLS.js) and this tool is detecting video tag size (on device screen?) and assuming lower resolution (so lower bitrate video is now served)... Either the code of that tool is edited not to do this resolution change or else Asker should directly access the right secondary M3U8 for their preferred resolution (if possible), finally they can also use MSE to manually load HD version